# Ajax Response throwing JavaScript Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, ajax

```js
function fnValidatePCRHours(pcr, hoursEntered)
  {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
             url : "/TMS/validatePCRHours.html?pcr="+pcr+"&hoursEntered="+hoursEntered,
             cache: false,
             success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
       {
           alert(data);
           return true;
       },
       error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
       {
      alert(errorThrown);
      return false;
       }
         });
   return false;
  }
```

As soon as i get response (IN) from server, i get script error. Can any one help me on this?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Javascript error.... Syntax error IN

Comment: is that all? i have never seen an error like that, i am sure that error doesnt end there

Comment: Yes... That's all i get. Do you see something faulty in my function?

Comment: @user1570656 _"As soon as i get response (IN) from server, i get script error."_ `$.ajax()` returns response from server ? Is `alert(data);` called ? Is error at `.then()` or `.done()` chained to  `fnValidatePCRHours`  ? Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Use `alert(jqXHR.responseText);` to check what is the error message. And let us know.

Comment: Added ...alert(jqXHR.responseText); and i get it as IN. But the same script error come and control stops over there